# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Category is not part of the schema for this Realm

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, annotation-processing

I using Android Studio 1.2.2 and Realm 0.81.1. 
I have created a Model 'Category' as follows:

```
@RealmClass
public class Category extends RealmObject {
   private String name;
   // getter and setter
}
```

But I am getting
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Category is not part of the schema for this Realm

I even enabled Annotation Processing, but the error is still persisting.

How can I solve this error? Any help is much appreciated.

**Update**

I dug deeper into the Realm code. I found that in Util.class file,

```
if(!superclass.equals(RealmObject.class)) {
        clazz = superclass;
    }
```

It is checking the superclass of the model I am using. When I printed out the super class of the mode; myself, like:

```
category.getClass().getSuperclass().getName();
```

I am getting 'io.realm.RealmObject' which is not equal to RealmObject.class. So Realm might not be considering it as a RealmObject.

Could this be the reason that is causing error?

Comment: When do you see the error message? Did you add the `Category` class in a newer version of your app and migrate the Realm file?

Comment: I see the error message on runtime, when I am trying to query the Realm. I didn't understand the second question. My app does not have any other db, creating from scratch with Realm so I don't have to migrate, right?

Comment: Have you got a chance to figure this out? I got this issue when enabling Proguard. Do you use ButterKnife?

Comment: @kodingralph no i still havent. and no i dont use ButterKnife.

Was it working for u before that ?

Comment: Yes, can you post your gradle console log?

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the annotation processing? I am using kotlin for realm. And I got the same problem until I use kapt to process the annotation.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I need to add realm plugin (apply plugin: 'realm-android') to every .gradle project that uses realm. RealRecyclerView and my main app project.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the order in which the plugins are specified in the build.gradle file of your app matters.  In my case, I had the apply plugin: 'realm-android' in it but apparently it was specified too early.  Putting it last worked.

This failed.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Yet this worked (note how real-android is last).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still have this issue but on my side I just clear the project and build again. Works fine after that... Please notice that I have android studio as ide.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two One-to-Many relationship. Two classes of the relationship were in different modules. This caused error. When I put them in the same module it worked. This is the related part from the source:

```
    public <E extends RealmModel> E copyOrUpdate(Realm realm, E obj, boolean update, Map<RealmModel, RealmObjectProxy> cache) {
    // This cast is correct because obj is either
    // generated by RealmProxy or the original type extending directly from RealmObject
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Class<E> clazz = (Class<E>) ((obj instanceof RealmObjectProxy) ? obj.getClass().getSuperclass() : obj.getClass());

    if (clazz.equals(Buddy.class)) {
        return clazz.cast(BuddyRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(realm, (Buddy) obj, update, cache));
    } else {
        throw getMissingProxyClassException(clazz);
    }
}
```